# Вызов хранимой процедуры с передачей параметров через php yii

Tags: php, sql, yii

Здраствуйте. Есть процедура

```
CREATE DEFINER=`123`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `coeficients_add`(IN `logistic` FLOAT, IN `vat` FLOAT, IN `manager` FLOAT, IN `curator` FLOAT, IN `admin` FLOAT, IN `status_add` INT, IN `sname` VARCHAR(50))
begin
DECLARE I INT;
DECLARE result INT;
Declare done integer default 0;
DECLARE curs CURSOR FOR select u.id FROM users AS u LEFT JOIN coefficients AS c ON u.id = c.user_id WHERE admin_coef IS NULL;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET done=1;
open curs;
while   done=0 DO
FETCH curs INTO result;
insert INTO `coefficients`(site_name,logistic, vat, manager_coef, curator_coef, admin_coef,user_id, status) values (sname,logistic,vat,manager,curator,admin,result,status_add);
END WHILE;
close curs;
end
```

В самом sql все работает как надо.
Хочу вызвать через йии и передать параметры

```
 $products = Yii::app()->db->createCommand("CALL coeficients_add('logistic','vat','manager','curator','admin','status','site')")
                    ->bindValue(':logistic', ($_POST['logistic']))
                    ->bindValue(':vat', ($_POST['vat']))
                    ->bindValue(':manager', ($_POST['manager']))
                    ->bindValue(':curator', ($_POST['curator']))
                    ->bindValue(':admin', ($_POST['admin']))
                    ->bindValue(':status',($_POST['status']))
                    ->bindValue(':site', quotemeta($site))
                    ->queryAll();
```

Но на выходе выдает ошибку :

```
CDbCommand не удалось исполнить SQL-запрос: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'logistic' in 'field list'. The SQL statement executed was: CALL coeficients_add(logistic,vat,manager,curator,admin,status,site)
```

В какую сторону копать? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Yii::app()->db->createCommand("CALL coeficients_add('logistic','vat','manager','curator','admin','status','site')")
```

Хм, к чему вы пытаетесь затем привязать параметры, если в запросе ни одного плейсхолдера нет, ни позиционного, ни именованного? Вроде Yii прозрачно проксирует запрос с параметрами в `PDO`, а не занимается сам разбором запроса.

Наверное, вы имели в виду

```
Yii::app()->db->createCommand("CALL coeficients_add(:logistic, :vat, :manager, :curator, :admin, :status, :site)")
```

Comment: В некотором роде помогло, но теперь не видит основной "миссии" процедуры - Column 'user_id' cannot be null. Хотя именно процедура овтечает за заполнение данного поля. Повторюсь, на чистом sql все работает отлично. Извиняють за формулировку, но впервые пробую вызов процедур с yii, теряюсь в догадках что не так.

Comment: Спасибо,то что нужно